# AWS EC2 instance wont load Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana

I am installing the ELK stack on an EC2 instance. I think my install was successful, but I can't load Kibana in my web browser. I think there are issues with my network setting but I am new to aws and I am not sure.

When I run

```
curl localhost:5601
```

I get

```
<script>var hashRoute = '/app/kibana';
var defaultRoute = '/app/kibana';

var hash = window.location.hash; 
if (hash.length) {
 window.location = hashRoute + hash;
} else {
 window.location = defaultRoute;
}</script>
```

When I then run this command on my instance ip

```
curl 174.129.93.100:5601
```

I get this, but I can ping successfully

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 174.129.93.100 port 5601: Connection refused”
```

I've had this problem for like a week and really need help solving it.

Comment: Does your security group allow TCP port 5601 inbound?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the port in security group is open as it says `Connection Refused`. Either the service is not running on the designated port or it is listening on localhost only.

In the kibana configuration, change from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to `Private IP` of the EC2 Instance and restart the service.

Check this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/kibana-server-properties.html

Comment: I was struggling with this and changing `server.host: "localhost"` to `server.host: "ec2_instance_private_ip"` got kibana to load! Thank you